# Press enter from text box to open link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which uses two text boxes to generate link onkeyup, if the user is in textbox 1 (All Others) and after typing some text he press enter key then "All cat link - sometext 1" generated link should be clicked, if he is in the "Category main" textbox and enters some text then he presses enter key 'Main Cat link - sometext 2' link should be clicked

```js
function allcat(e) {
  var myVar = jQuery('#allcat').val();
  jQuery("#anchor").html("<a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.com/page.php?search=" + myVar + "&order=DESC'>All cat Link - " + myVar + "</a>");
  return false;
}

function catMain(e) {
  var myVar = jQuery('#catMain').val();
  jQuery("#anchorMain").html("<a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.com/page.php?category=main&search=" + myVar + "&order=DESC'>Main Cat Link - " + myVar + "</a>");
  return false;
}

jQuery(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    jQuery("#anchorMain").trigger('click');     
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Generate Link</h1>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>All Others</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="50" name="allcat" id="allcat" onkeyup="allcat()">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category main</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="50" name="catMain" id="catMain" onkeyup="catMain()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr><br>

<span id="anchor">All Category</span><br><br><br>
<span id="anchorMain">Cat main</span>
```

Comment: Show us your code, which you have tried so far.

Comment: The 'link' elements are `span` which have no event handlers on them... why would clicking them do anything?

Comment: Also note that I placed the code from the fiddle in the question itself. Please do this in future. An an image of the result without code is next to useless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, can you please tell me how i solve this problem ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have found other way of doing this by javascript document.location = $("#anchor4 a").attr('href'); can you please tell me how can i open it in new tab ?

Comment: Put `target="blank"` on the `a` elements in your HTML

Comment: target="blank" is written, but still it is opening in the same tab

Comment: target="_blank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/L2n6esnc/

```js
allcat = function(e) {
  var myVar = jQuery('#allcat').val();
  $("#anchor").html(`<a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.com/page.php?search=${myVar}&order=DESC'>All cat Link - ${myVar}</a>`);
  return false;
}

catMain = function(e) {
  var myVar = jQuery('#catMain').val();
  $("#anchorMain").html(`<a target='_blank' href='http://www.example.com/page.php?category=main&search=${myVar}&order=DESC'>Main Cat Link - ${myVar}</a>`);
  return false;
}

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    window.open($('#' + $(this).attr('appendTo') + ' a').attr('href'), '_blank')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Generate Link</h1>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>All Others</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="50" name="allcat" id="allcat" onkeyup="allcat()" appendTo="anchor">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category main</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="50" name="catMain" id="catMain" onkeyup="catMain()" appendTo="anchorMain">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr><br>

<span id="anchor">All Category</span><br><br><br>
<span id="anchorMain">Cat main</span>
```

I've used `ES6` `backtick` and `${}` for using variable instead of double/single quotes.

Instead of triggering a `click` event, I've used `window.open`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing... In HTML I have added an attribute named 'appendTo'...  Check in input tag.

Comment: please check the jsfiddle... an attribute added in HTML in input textbox tag and updated keyup event method in JavaScript.

Comment: yes its working now, sorry i forgot to add this  appendTo="anchorMain" in my code, i just copied the javascript code

Comment: Thanks @Shiladitya

Answer (score 1):

on final keyup, don't click on `#anchorMain` (which as Rory says, is a span), click on `#anchorMain>a`

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          if (event.target.id === 'catMain') {
              jQuery("#anchorMain a")[0].click();     
          } else if (event.target.id === 'allcat') {
              jQuery("#anchor a")[0].click();     
          }
      }
});
```

Note the addition of `[0]` to the jquery.click(). The problem is jQuery().click() will call event handlers registered on the element. Alas, navigation isn't jquery-type registered handler.  By doing `jQuery("#anchorMain a")[0]` you're getting the DOM element, upon which you're calling the DOM .click()... which will do what you want.

Finally, you need to figure out "which" link to click on, when the user presses enter. You can do that from the `document` level, by looking at event.target.

Comment: jQuery(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Right, because you'll need to determine if you should be clicking on allcat or catMain. I've added that code for you also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<form>` tag and and get work done inside submit function like

```
<form action="someFunction()">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now you can retrieve the values inside the function and manipulate or do your work accordingly.
Cleanest way to do i guess.